# Master Password & security key approach

Tags: database, security, cryptography, passwords

I'm currently doing some research on encryption and have read the whitepaper of 1Password (Password Manager) and other tools. I would like to write a small application that can do something similar, just for testing purposes to understand the whole thing better. My approach would be the following:

**Master Password** - only known by the user, not stored on the system or anywhere else, has to be typed in manually.

**Security Key** - a 26-digit randomly-generated key stored in the Windows Credential Manager / macOS Keychain, only on the user's system

User enters Master Password, Security Key is retrieved. The security key (even if it is indirectly known because it is on the user's system) is combined with the master password and hashed (SHA-512) and then used as a key when encrypting / decrypting the database (AES-256-CBC). The hashed combination is not stored on device or saved.

Now four questions arise here:

1. is it bad if the initialization vector is known? It should be generated randomly, but it must be stored somewhere so that it is always available.
2. do I see it right, that if a component (Master Password or Security Key) is missing, no access is possible? Master Password forgotten => data gone, Key deleted and no longer known => data gone?
3. accordingly, attacker must know master password AND key to gain access? If he has the key, he has to guess the master password, if he has the master password, he has to get the key. Is this understood correctly?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thanks! I edited my text. I do this in Qt / C++, so I thought it was kinda related to it. Removed the tag... Question 3 is generally meant if the attacker can get any access to the database when I do it like I explained.

Comment: So the only difference between 2 and 3 is if the user or an attacker tries to access it? Technically it's the same question.

Comment: Technically, but an attacker tries different things than a normal user to get access to the database. The question is meant to be if the approach is so secure, that an attacker wouldn't even start trying it.

Comment: So you expect different answers for _"if a component is missing, no access is possible?"_ and _"attacker must know master password AND key to gain access?"_ If you can answer question 3 with "no" you have to answer question 2 also with "no" and vice versa. Or could you elaborate the difference between possible user access and possible attacker access.

Comment: The answer to your questions depends on the details, most importantly, how you would "combine" the master password with the security key. There is really a lot to this, but in this scheme you should encrypt the key with another key derived from the password with a proper kdf. But this is all off topic on SO, and also too broad.

Answer (score 0):

The initialization vector (or nonce) is public and is stored unencrypted with the data.  Different algorithms and cipher modes require different things of it, but it should always be generated either from a key derivation function or from a secure CSPRNG.

If you implement this approach securely, yes, it would be impossible to recover the data without both components.  I would use scrypt or Argon2i to turn the passphrase into a key, and then use that plus the security key as the salt in HKDF to derive a key-encrypting key.  There are other secure approaches as well, including just using the security key as the salt in scrypt or Argon2i.  All of these approaches would require both piece of data to have any hope of decryption.

Comment: The idea with both as salt is great. I need to read a little bit more about HKDF but this will work out. Many thanks!